# Broken packages in Kali on Raspberry Pi - fix-broken install does not work?

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I just set up Kali Linux on my raspberry pi and after updating & upgrading I received the following dependency issues - even after running `apt --fix-broken install` multiple times I seem to not be able to correct those.

Apparently policykit-1 is dependant on newer versions of the packages as listed below. I can not remove those individually as there are dependancies on other packages.

Anyone having an idea on how to overcome this or to repair apt?

```
root@kali-pi:~# apt full-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 policykit-1 : Depends: libpolkit-agent-1-0 (= 0.105-20) but 0.105-21 is installed
               Depends: libpolkit-backend-1-0 (= 0.105-20) but 0.105-21 is installed
               Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (= 0.105-20) but 0.105-21 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@kali-pi:~#
```

Comment: Although this is about Kali, this is not a security question.

Answer (score 2):

*(I tried to comment when this question was still on Security.StackExchange so please excuse the full-fledged Answer post instead of the comment due to my missing privileges here at Superuser)*

Kali is notorious for bad update/dependency management. While this might not answer your question *(hence I'd have posted it as a comment)*, the following might be feasible depending on your situation under the assumption:

I stopped doing updates/upgrades on Kali *and* I stopped using it outside of VMs for penetration tests. My current approach which saved me tons of time is to set up Kali once in a VM and configure it to the extent of:

- set language and keyboard mapping,
- working folder-share with the host OS,
- working network setup for NAT and potentially Bridge/Host-Only, depending on your needs

Once this is done, I simply create a snapshot of the VM and use it just as usual (copy & paste should work with VBox Guest Additions). If Kali breaks due to the plethora of potential reasons, I just reset it to the snapshot. Just make sure all relevant files are inside the shared folder, so you don't accidentally delete important files (pcaps, notes, flags etc.)

Think of Kali as the one-way gloves you get at gas stations: good for the dirty work, but discarded after a few uses.

Comment: This is exactly how I use Kali too, though recently I have switched to vanilla Debian with the packages Kali comes with installed.